# Alignment issue between lightning-input fields in lwc

Tags: lwc

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCWsw.png)

The problem is that there is a huge space between the datetime input field and the text field. How do i fix it? I have used slds-size and also css width property.But none of that works

What should I do to fix it?

I have used slds-grid for the input fields. The 2nd row code is as follows

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">

                <div class="slds-col slds-m-left_small">

                    <label for="rcdt"><div class="required-field">Receiving Date Time</div></label>

                    <lightning-input id="rcdt" variant="label-hidden" type="datetime"></lightning-input>

                  </div>



                <div class="slds-col">

                    <label for="delnoid">Delivery Note Number</label>

                    <lightning-input type="text" variant="label-hidden" id="delnoid"></lightning-input>

                </div>

             

                <div class="slds-col slds-m-right_small">

                    <label for="notesid">Notes</label>

                    <lightning-input type="text" variant="label-hidden" id="notesid"></lightning-input>

                </div>  

            </div>
```